# Controller won't load data from database

Tags: c#, database, controller

I am currently making a controller to gather myself the data i need from a database. I am not allowed to use Entity Framework and i can't seem to find the reason my controller won't load the data from my SQL server... It is locally hosted on my computer and the connecntion string i am using is in the controller file itself.

Thanks in advance!

I have removed the data context from my controller because i can't share them

```
namespace ControllerFile.Controller
{
    internal class ControllerFile
    {
        private static string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[""].ConnectionString;

        public GroupModel GetModel(int Id)
        {
            string sqlQuery = " Query ";

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("", );

                    con.Open();

                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Model user = new Model();

                            return user;
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Error");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return new Model();
        }


        public void AddNewItem(Model, model)
        {
            string sqlQuery = " QUERY ";

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("", model.id);

                    con.Open();

                    try
                    {
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error");
                    }

                }
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

The result should be a proper connection to my database where my listview loads the correct data. I have added a hardcoded variable with a filled model and that one did load into the listview. So we can rule that code out. It has to be in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the data you get from the database anywhere in that code. You do this:

```cs
while (reader.Read())
```

but then you never actually get any data from the data reader. You just do this:

```cs
Model user = new Model();

return user;
```

so you're just returning a new, empty model, no matter what you get from the database. You need to actually get the appropriate data from the data reader and put it in the model, e.g.

```cs
Model user = new Model {SomeProperty = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("SomeColumn"))};

return user;
```

Comment: I feel really dumb right now.... I had removed the data context for this post but i never thought about the fact i forgot to add the Model data in the first place. :facepalm: